# Is it possible to create a web-component of PDFjs

Tags: blazor, maui, pdf.js, maui-blazor

We're developing a file explorer with a PDF viewer in our MAUI-Blazor application. We need an open-source or free PDF viewer, as we're pre-revenue. Our requirements are:

- Capability for importing and exporting annotations (does not need to be saved in the PDF)
- Controlled via C# (or at least JavaScript)
- Ability to render base64 encoded PDFs

We've considered using [PDFjs](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/), but its integration, primarily via an iFrame, is unsuitable. My attempt to build a Web Component using [@open-wc](https://open-wc.org/) and [pdfjs-dist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdfjs-dist) (follwing the [example](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) of using PDFjs in a canvas) was unsuccessful due to required NodeJS package dependencies (specifically "fs") that would error-out. But I cannot be sure that I did everything correctly.
Additionally, [this library](https://github.com/alekswebnet/pdfjs-viewer-element) partially met our needs but suffered from flickering issues on search and is also using an iFrame. In short: A web-component using @open-wc and pdfjs-dist without IFrame would be my personal favorite.
Currently we are resigning to the fate of having to use PDFjs within an iFrame.

Options we have ruled out:

- PDFjs Express: Requires payment for annotations.
- PSPDFKIT: No free tier and undisclosed pricing.
- Syncfusion: Paid and not up to our standards.

I'm seeking advice on this matter, as there must be others facing similar constraints in search of a robust PDF viewer.

Comment: Well .. alas Stackoverflow has a rule about not suggesting specifics like this, as its opinion based and will just get all kinds of answers instead of a correct one.  That being said, if you can't find a free one for a trial, maybe you can email a paid on and explain your plans and perhaps they can work with you.

Comment: @KJ yes of course, I just receive the Base64 string from the backend and want the reader to be able to convert it.

Comment: The author of ‘pdfjs-viewer-element’ here.
Could you please clarify about “but suffered from flickering issues”? Also I would be very pleased if you open the issue in the repo.
https://github.com/alekswebnet/pdfjs-viewer-element/issues/new

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I do not have the code anymore, but when you go to your example api page: https://alekswebnet.github.io/pdfjs-viewer-element/#api an type into the search bar, the whole component flickers. I think it's because the iframe is reloading when the href changes.

Answer (score 1):

Syncfusion has a free community edition. Your revenue must be less than $1 million per year.  Sounds like you qualify.

Answer (score 0):

The official PDF.js viewer is adding annotation support recently, but I think it's still active developing stage, not production ready.

If you want to build a custom viewer as good as the default PDF.js viewer based on `pdfjs-dist`, I think it take a lot of work and you need someone who are very familiar with the PDF.js project.

If you only don't want integrate the PDF.js viewer with the iframe solution, you can try https://github.com/Priestch/document-viewer/, it's built with vanalia Javascript and easy to integrate with any project.